# Putting arrays inside of objects using Swagger 2.0 and YAML

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am currently learning how to document using Swagger because my company is evaluating using it as a standard way of documenting for upcoming projects.

I read online that using YAML is easier to read than using JSON, and since YAML is a subset of JSON I figured it would be alright.

I'm working on the response for the 200 code, I would like to represent something similar to the following structure:

```
responses:
    200:
      description: OK.
      schema:
        title: response
        type: object
        items:
          properties:
            title: user
            type: array
            items:
                id:
                  type: string
                name:
                  type: string
            status:
              type: integer
```

Basically I return an object called "response" that contains two variables: An array called "user" that contains several strings (I included just two for the sake of clarity) and another variable (outside of the "user" array) called "status" that contains an integer.

The above code doesn't work, and the editor notifies me that it isn't a "valid response definition".

I'm not sure how to tackle this. I'd appreciate some help on what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically I return an object called "response" that contains two variables: An array called "user" that contains several strings (I included just two for the sake of clarity) and another variable (outside of the "user" array) called "status" that contains an integer.

Based on your description, the response is supposed to be as follows (assuming the response is JSON). Basically, you have an object with a nested object:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": "12345",
    "name": "Alice"
  },
  "status": 0
}
```

This response can be defined as follows:

```
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK.
          schema:
            title: response
            type: object
            required: [user, status]
            properties:
              user:
                type: object
                required: [id, name]
                properties:
                  id:
                    type: string
                  name:
                    type: string
              status:
                type: integer
```

For convenience, complex schemas with nested objects can be broken down into individual object schemas. Schemas can be written in the global `definitions` section and referenced from other places via `$ref`. This way, for example, you can reuse the same schema in multiple operations/responses.

```
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK.
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ResponseModel"

definitions:
  ResponseModel:
    title: response
    type: object
    properties:
      user:
        $ref: "#/definitions/User"
      status:
        type: integer
    required:
      - user
      - status

  User:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
      name:
        type: string
    required:
      - id
      - name
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried the way you suggested but I still get the _not a valid response_ error. Something I don't understand is, how do I define the key-value pairs inside the string array? I have been using `items:  {nameofkey}:  type: string` but I still get _indentation error_

Comment: @RolaTarola: 1) Make sure your indentation is correct and the `responses` section is correctly indented under your operation definition.

Comment: 2) So `users` is an associative array/dictionary, not a regular string array? Does it have any fixed/required keys or are all keys arbitrary?

Comment: The keys are always the same. In my OP I detailed only two keys for the sake of clarity (`id` and `name`) but they will always be fixed.

Comment: it worked! Thank you! Indentation sure is hard to nail while using YAML though.